# How to work with multiple ids in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, smarty

Following is my HTML code :

```
    <table>
{foreach in smarty starts}
    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" id ="show_answer"><p  id="show_ans"><b>View Answer : </b></p></td>
                        <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top" id ="hide_answer"><b>Answer is here</b><br/><p  id="hide_ans" >Hide Answer</p></td>
                        <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top">
                        </td>

                      </tr>
{foreach in smarty ends}                      
                    </table>
```

My jQuery code is here :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show_ans").click(function(){ 
    $("#show_answer").hide(500);
    $("#hide_answer").show(500);
  });
  $("#hide_ans").click(function(){
    $("#hide_answer").hide(500);
    $("#show_answer").show(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

Actually there are multiple such `<tr>` tags and multiple related ids (i.e multiple `show_ans` and `show_ans` ids). Now when I'm trying with my code it is functioning properly only for the first record as it matches with only first ids combination.

But I have to make the code workable for each of the ids combination individually.
But I don't know how to assign different ids generated dynamically and use them in my jQuery code.
In short, the functionality should work for individual `<tr>`, so that the ids should be unique and the jQuery function should work appropriately.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use css class it is just as simple as using ids.

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe Can you explain me with sample code how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<table>
i=1;
{foreach in smarty starts}
<tr>
     <td valign="top" id ="show_answer">
      <p  id="show_ans"+i><b>View Answer : </b></p>
     </td>
     <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top">
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td valign="top" id ="hide_answer"><b>Answer is here</b><br/>
       <p  id="hide_ans"+i >Hide Answer</p>
     </td>
     <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top">
     </td>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".show_ans"+i).click(function(){
       $(this).parent().hide(500);
       $(this).parent().next().show(500);
      });

     $(".hide_ans"+i).click(function(){
       $(this).parent().hide(500);
       $(this).parent().prev().show(500);
     });
 });
 </script>
 i+=1;

</tr>
{foreach in smarty ends}                      
</table>
```

This is not execute code, But Same type Once I have resolve my problem.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. But can you help me with smart? I'm having smarty file not simple html file and I am confused in attaching the i variable to the string. Can you help me out please? My code snippet from smarty is . Tell me is it right?
{assign var='i' value=1}
        {foreach from=$all_chapter_ques item=chapter_ques key=key}
       <p id="show_ans{$i}"><b>View Answer : </b></p></td>
                    
       {assign var='i' value=$i+1}

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Ids must be unique on page. If there are more than one elements with same id only first one will be returned by query selector api.
You must either use classes instead of ids or you should generate unique ids in your loop. I would use classes if I was you.

Comment: I'm agree with you. Even I tried classes as you said. But If I use classes instead of ids it affects all the elements present within a document. And my requirement is it should work for individual element and I don't know how to assign multiple ids and make the code workable for them.

Answer (score 0):

Really you should be using classes instead of ID's (in the name, unique identifier).

Something like this may work with ids? (written form memory so may need some tweaking)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show_ans").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().show(500);
        $(this).parent().hide(500);
    });

    $("#hide_ans").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().prev().show(500);
        $(this).parent().hide(500);
    });
});
```

If not, change them to classes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show_ans").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().show(500);
        $(this).parent().hide(500);
    });

    $(".hide_ans").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide(500);
        $(this).parent().prev().show(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's same as my code. Working for first element only. I want the code to be executed for individual <tr> element. So classes could not be used in such case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  {foreach in smarty starts}
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class ="show_answer"><p  id="show_ans"><b>View Answer : </b></p></td>
    <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class ="hide_answer"><b>Answer is here</b><br/>
      <p  id="hide_ans" >Hide Answer</p></td>
    <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top"></td>
  </tr>
  {foreach in smarty ends}
</table>
```

and JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show_ans").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide(500);
        $(this).parent().next().show(500);
    });

    $(".hide_ans").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide(500);
        $(this).parent().prev().show(500);
    });
});
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/aMWHN/1/

Comment: It's same as my code. Working for first element only. I want the code to be executed for individual <tr> element. So classes could not be used in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping the code it is better to use class than id attribute.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" class ="show_answer">
            <p  class="show_ans"><b>View Answer : </b></p>
        </td>
        <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td valign="top" class ="hide_answer">
            <b>Answer is here</b><br/>
            <p  class="hide_ans" >Hide Answer</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right" width="7%" valign="top">
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$(".show_ans").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').hide().next('tr').show()
});

$(".hide_ans").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').hide().prev('tr').show()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using DOM to select your different lines, esp. if you have a table of elements.

$("TR:first"): First line

$("TR:eq(3)") : 4th line

$("TR:last"): Lastline

$("TR:odd"), $("TR:even"), $("TR:nth-child(odd)") etc..

Hope this helps ...

Si